# Have to include RewriteEngine Off in sub directory or I get " Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects "

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following RewriteRule on the .htaccess in the root diectory. It simply changes the location and includes an additional parameter:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /application/auth\.php\?(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /application/external/external.php?f=CheckThese[L,QSA]
```

I get "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error" in the log with an internal server error.

The strange thing is that if I put a .htaccess file with RewriteEngine Off in the /application/external directory I no longer get the error.

I have the follwing in the .htaccess in the root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !.*outputstuffwithouthttps.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsitedomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have only two more rewrite rules in the .htaccess file in the root doing the same thing. They already have the .htaccess file with RewriteEngine Off in the directory that is being directed to. I took a gamble and put the same file in the other sub directoy and discovered this solved the problem.

If I remark out the rules that change the port 80 to https it does not change anything so I dont think this is the cause.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /application/auth\.php\? [NC]
RewriteRule (?:^|/)application/auth\.php$ /application/external/external.php?f=CheckThese [L,QSA,NC]
```

Otherwise your rule will cause infinite looping due to the fact that `%{THE_REQUEST}` never changes as you're doing internal rewrite only.

Comment: Thanks again and it works. It seems I dont even need "RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /application/auth\.php\? [NC]" . It works fine without it

Comment: Yes that may not be required at all